# How to display value obtained from server on the browser console?

Tags: html, typescript, angular5, angular-httpclient

I tried to retrieve value from a server using httpclient get method in angular. But I am unable to view it either on the console or on the webpage. How do I do that?

Typescript File:

```
export class CountryComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
   country:Observable<Country[]>;
   ngOnInit() {
     this.country=this.http.get<Country[]>(path+"/getAllCountries");
         console.log(this.country);           
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let count of country">
     {{(count.id}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: observables are getting executed if there is atleast one subscriber. so try `this.country=this.http.get<Country[]>(path+"/getAllCountries").subscribe();`

Comment: @Denisx it is wrong. `subscribe` method returns a `subscription` not the observable response.

Comment: Check in the Network View if the requests actually returns 200 first you van also Check the Content there and get i go on wether the request was actually sent

Answer (score 1):

You should either use `async` pipe or `subscribe` to http request.

---

First way `async`. Let Angular deal with subscription itself

```
   <li *ngFor="let count of country | async">
     {{(count.id}}
    </li>
```

---

Second way `subscribe`:

```
export class CountryComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

   country:Observable<Country[]> = [];

   ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<Country[]>(path+"/getAllCountries").subscribe(response => {
        this.country = response;
        console.log(this.country);
    })         
  }
```

---

You can have a look at the official tutorials `Http` section:

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6